# SQL Server 2016 linked Oracle Server - Suddenly stopped working

Tags: oracle, sql-server-2016, linked-server, tns

After rebooting my Windows Server 2016 Standard (SQL Server 2016) my SSIS process that runs this query:

```
select * from openquery(HRMPROD, 'SELECT QUERY HERE' )
```

started failing with this error:

[image]

I get the same error if I try to run the query in SSMS.  I have the same linked server set up on my test instance and the query is successful when I run it there.  I have compared the linked server create script on both instances and it is the same.

Any idea where I should look for what is causing the connection issue on the one server but not the other?

Thank you.

Comment: Hmmm maybe firewall related? Smells like a network issue, like DNS.

Answer (score 3):

Saying the answer is on the Oracle side is just like pointing fingers across the way.  Let's just fix the issue here.

There is a connection string that is used from SSIS, (which you also used in SSMS)  The connection string contains three main components to connect and would result in the 12154 error if any of them were incorrect:

- Host
- Instance name (different than Instance on Sql Server, think database name)
- port

The port most likely hasn't change, neither has the database name, but the host...No, hasn't changed, but the DNS server used to connect most likely has!  I would ping the host and see what returns from the SSIS and your SSMS host that you're using.  I would expect it to fail.  Find out what IP address the host is using and ping that -  see if it returns.  I'm guessing that's the change that needs to be updated or your Network folks need to fix a DNS configuration/server issue.

Hope this helps!
Kellyn

Answer (score 0):

Since you are getting a response from the TNS Listener, the problem lies on the Oracle side. See [Architecture of Oracle Network Services](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/network.111/b28316/architecture.htm#NETAG004) for an overview of how the Oracle networking handles things. Keep in mind that based on the error message you've reached the TNS Listener, so you only need to check things between TNS and the Oracle database... In other words, your networking and SQL Server settings are fine or you wouldn't be able to get this error message.

Answer (score 0):

I would agree with above that the issue might have to do with the network. I have come across that a few times, where we can set everything up, but a firewall is blocking communication between the two servers.

Open up powershell on the new server and run a tracert to the target to see the hops and identify if is connecting across the network.

If it is, then run a test-netconnect on the specific port, to see if the port is open from the firewalls.

Cheers!